# Only open certain file extension and checking if the first two parts of that file are integers

Tags: c++-cli, file-extension

The program I am writing opens a .DAT file with the given format:

> ```
> 10 10
> OO+E+OO+++
> O++O+O+OOO
> OOOOOO+O+O
> +++++O++OO
> OOO+OOO+O+
> O+O+O+++O+
> O+O+OOO+OO
> ++O+++O++O
> O+OOOOO++O
> O+O++O+OOO
> ```

1. How can I block the user from opening any other file extension other than .DAT? For example, if they attempt to open a .PNG file, it will throw the MessageBox below of "Not a proper maze file!"
2. I also want this to happen when the first two parts of the file once opened are not both integers.

   ```
   OpenFileDialog ^ fileDialog = gcnew OpenFileDialog();
   fileDialog->InitialDirectory = ".";
   if (fileDialog->ShowDialog() == ::DialogResult::OK)
   {
      wchar_t fileName[1024];
      for (int i = 0; i < fileDialog->FileName->Length; i++)
         fileName[i] = fileDialog->FileName[i];
      fileName[fileDialog->FileName->Length] = '\0';

      ifstream ifs;
      ifs.open(fileName);
      maze = new Maze( mazePanel, ifs );
      ifs.close();
      if (maze->IsValid())
      {
         showOriginalBtn->Show();
         mazePanel->Show();
      }
      else
      {
         MessageBox::Show( "Not a proper maze file!" );
         mazePanel->Hide();
      }
   }
   ```

Here is the code where I am reading in the maze file and storing it into its proper places:

```
   valid = true;
   free = false;
   ifs >> width >> height;
   if ( width <= MAXSIZE && height <= MAXSIZE)
   {
      panel = drawingPanel;
      panel->Width = width * CELLSIZE;
      panel->Height = height * CELLSIZE;
   }
   else
      valid = false;

   char value;
   for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
      {
         ifs >> value;
         if (value != EXIT && value != DEADEND && value != OPEN)
         {
            valid = false;
            return;
         }
         orig[j][i] = value;
         solved[j][i] = value;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Filter` property of the OpenFileDialog to set the extensions that are displayed. Something like:

```
fileDialog->Filter = ".dat";
```

Comment: What if they type in the actual name? I need to the program to pop up the message box.

Comment: Use the Path.GetExtension method from System.IO to check for DAT.

Answer (score 0):

1. look for the last occurence of '.' and the next text will be the extension; compare it to DAT.
2. didn't quite understand what you need, so I will assume you meant you need a check for the first 2 parts. In this case, you can do `if (std::cin >> int1 && std::cin >> int2) { /*...*/ }`. >> will return false if the format of the input does not match the type of `int1` and `int2`.

--Edit
Responding to your comment, here is how you could iterate over a wchar_t[].

```
    wchar_t t[] = { 'a', 'b', '.', 'D', 'A', 'T' };

    std::wstring s;

    for (int i = 5; t[i] != '.'; i--) {

        s = t[i] + s;

    }

    std::wcout << s << std::endl; //DAT
```

Comment: 1. The use of the wchar_t array is confusing me. I understand this process using a regular string, can you elaborate further?

2. That is what I meant. Thank you! I apologize for not clearly getting that question across.

Comment: It actually looks like my second case also covered my first case because inputting a PNG file would still fail that statement!

For the first question, I'd have to sit down and figure out how to convert that method when using wchar_t. I do understand what you are talking about though.

Comment: From what I know, a wchar_t is simply a wide character type, wide meaning a char is not only (USUALLY) 1 byte large. Iterating through an array of wchar_t should be the same as iterating through an array of chars (aside from the chars hex representation). You should start from the end and move back until you find a "."

Comment: That makes sense and definitely something I will look into on a side project. Thanks again.

Comment: Still, we usually say just `std::wstring t = L"ab.DAT";`. But this code has more style issues; such as not using `.find(L'.')` and other string methods.

Comment: @MSalters You do realize wstring != wchar_t[] right? Good. Also, that code is just an example of how he could iterate over a wchar_t[], but I'm sure you read through the comments(2nd) before commenting. Moreover, this has nothing to do with style. Using K&R block is a matter of style. If you wanna nitpick errors here, you should change your find to find_last_of.

Comment: Course I realize they're different. That's why I recommend one over the other.